# section scrolling using mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I'm using the mousewheel plugin to scroll sections of my page.

What I should look into for disabling the function I wrote until the animation has fully completed?

I am running stop() but that only cancels out the animation.

```
$('section').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {

$('section' ).waypoint(function(direction){
    thisID = $(this); 
},{ offset: '25%' });

if (delta > 0) {
    console.log('up');
    if ($(this).not(":first-child")) { 
        //$(this).animate(function(){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: thisID.prev().offset().top
        }, 1000);
            //});
    }else {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: thisID.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    }
else if (delta < 0) {

    if ($(this).not(":first-child")) { 
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: thisID.next().offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: thisID.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }

    console.log('down');
}
return false; // prevent default
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a "stoplight" variable.  Set it to `False` at the beginning of your function, and then re-set it to `True` at the end of the animation using the `complete` argument of the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.  Then make the main function only run if this variable is `True`.

Comment: Thank you I was able to get it to work using your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel you might want to take a look at things such as [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

It will save you from many headaches when you start dealing with touch devices, touch screens, old browsers, kinetic scrolling present in trackpads or Apple laptops...